# Pandas read_csv not recognizing ISO8601 as datetime dtype

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Currently I am using pandas to read a csv file into a `DataFrame`, using the first column as the index. The first column is in ISO 8601 format, so according to the documentation for [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), it should be recognized as a datetime:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)

In [3]: print df.head()
                        U     V     Z    Ubar    Udir
2014-11-01 00:00:00  0.73 -0.81  0.46  1.0904  317.97
2014-11-01 01:00:00  1.26 -1.50  0.32  1.9590  319.97
2014-11-01 02:00:00  1.50 -1.80  0.13  2.3431  320.19
2014-11-01 03:00:00  1.39 -1.65  0.03  2.1575  319.89
2014-11-01 04:00:00  0.94 -1.08 -0.03  1.4318  318.96
```

However, when querying the index dtype, it returns 'object':

```
In [4]: print df.index.dtype
object
```

I then have to manually convert it to datetime dtype:

```
In [5]: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

In [6]: print df.index.dtype
datetime64[ns]
```

Is there any way to automatically have the index set to datetime dtype when calling `read_csv()`?

Comment: You've not told it to parse the column as a datetime `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates = 0, index_col=0)`

Comment: Yup, that did the trick! For some reason when I read the documentation for `read_csv` I thought `parse_dates` defaulted to `True`, probably from reading: "If True -> try parsing the index"

Comment: I've always found this aspect of the `read_csv` docs to be ambiguous and possibly incorrect, I've always had to pass the integer index, note you have to pass as a list if you want to parse multiple columns like so: `parse_dates=[0,3,4]` and nested lists if you want it to parse multiple columns as a single datetime col: `parse_dates=[[0,1]]`. So I've noticed that setting `parse_dates=True` just doesn't work so I always pass a list or single int for the column index

Comment: Yeah, I've used `parse_dates` and `date_parser` before when I've had to combine multiple columns. Hmm, that's odd, `parse_dates=True` seems to work fine with my current setup (python 2.7.8 x64, pandas 0.15.1)

Comment: strange still fails for me using your data on python 3.3.5 64-bit, pandas 0.15.1

Comment: Good to know for future reference! Should save me some head scratching... if I can remember it that is ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation describes parse_dates parameter:

> parse_dates : boolean or list of ints or names or list of lists or dict, default False 
>   - boolean. If True -> try parsing the index. 
>   - list of ints or names. e.g. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column. 
>   - list of lists. e.g. If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as
>   a single date column. 
>   - dict, e.g. {‘foo’ : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’ 
>   Note: A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.

Since you want to parse index you can use:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

I just added column name for first column in csv file.

```
                 Date     U     V     Z    Ubar    Udir
0  2014-11-01 00:00:00  0.73 -0.81  0.46  1.0904  317.97
1  2014-11-01 01:00:00  1.26 -1.50  0.32  1.9590  319.97
2  2014-11-01 02:00:00  1.50 -1.80  0.13  2.3431  320.19
3  2014-11-01 03:00:00  1.39 -1.65  0.03  2.1575  319.89
4  2014-11-01 04:00:00  0.94 -1.08 -0.03  1.4318  318.96

df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

If you want to drop the date column, you can use

```
df = df.drop('Date', 1)
```