# convert data frame datatime string to float in python /Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, data-conversion

i have this big data file that is about 1 million records. when i read it with pandas it doesn't let me convert the datetime string values to floats.

i tried converting it to a numpy array and float32 but it didn't let me do the second

```
data = pd.read_csv('s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-881385135648/data/all_data.csv', header= None, encoding='utf8', low_memory=False)
type(data)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2018-06-27 15:31:54.053'

Comment: Why would you convert `2018-06-27 15:31:54.053` to float? What is that float value do you expect?

Comment: If you want the timestamps in epoch time you're going to need to convert them to a some sort of date dtype so `numpy` or `pandas` knows what to do with it. Try `pd.Timestamp('2018-06-27 15:31:54.053').value`

Comment: but how do i do that for a whole column?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import time

timeString= '2018-06-27 15:31:54.053'

dateTime1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

time_float = float(time.mktime(dateTime1.timetuple()))
```

Don't know if this is the best solution but this is a solution I have in one of my projects

Comment: here is what the data looks like :2017-06-26 22:37:00
2017-06-26 22:43:26.530
2017-06-28 12:27:42.770
0
0
0
0
0
0
2019-05-23 19:22:07.657
2019-05-24 12:15:40.233
2019-05-23 20:59:31.223
2019-05-24 12:02:47.793
0
0
0
0
0
2
2017-06-25 22:59:00
2017-06-26 14:21:25.663
2017-06-26 14:21:25.663
0
0
2017-06-26 14:45:34.910
2017-07-12 18:43:20.877
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2017-06-26 15:06:00
2017-06-26 22:22:00
3
2017-06-26 00:42:00
2017-07-08 12:10:56.713
2017-07-08 12:10:56.713
0
0
2017-06-26 17:29:13.807
2017-07-13 18:50:38.357
and all columns are just that.

Comment: here is the error :ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2018-06-27 15:31:54.053'

Comment: @vanetoj try this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276816/pandas-read-csv-not-recognizing-iso8601-as-datetime-dtype

Comment: well i did this :data=data.values

data=data.reshape(-1,1)
data.shape and then this:data=np.datetime64() so it worked but now i m down to different mistakes. well ya, and the way i read the file was this after all: data = pd.read_csv('s3://awscoxautolabs59-eu-central-1-logs-coxautomotive/all_data.csv', encoding='utf8',parse_dates=True, low_memory=False,na_filter=True)